# ExtJs combo forced to select the first item (with example code)

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a combo B that gets loaded by other combo A (triggered by 'select' listener)
once B is populated, I see all items but now from drop-down in Combo B, 
I'm force to select the first item with mouse 
I can select other item only by typing 

Please help!!!!

code for Combo A

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    displayField: 'value',
    emptyText: 'Please select A first',
    fieldLabel: 'Combo A',
    id: 'comboA',
    maxHeight: 240,
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    typeAhead: true,
    typeAheadDelay: 100,
    valueField: 'id',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: '/cgi-bin/server.cgi',
        fields: ['id', 'name'],
        baseParams: {
            action: 'getAList'
        },
        autoLoad: true,
        root: 'aList'
    }),
    listeners: {
        'select': {
            fn: function(){
                var comboB = Ext.getCmp('comboB');
                comboB.clearValue();
                comboB.store.removeAll();
                comboB.store.reload({
                    params: {
                        id: this.getValue()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for combo B:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    displayField: 'item',
    editable: true,
    emptyText: 'Select a Combo A first',
    fieldLabel: 'Combo B',
    id: 'comboB',
    lazyInit: true,
    maxHeight: 240,
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    typeAhead: true,
    valueField: 'id',
    width: 220,
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: '/cgi-bin/server.cgi',
        root: 'bList',
        autoLoad: false,
        fields: ['id,', 'item'],
        baseParams: {
            action: 'getBList'
        },
        listeners: {
            'beforeload': function(){
                Ext.getCmp('comboB').disable();
            },
            'load': function(){
                Ext.getCmp('comboB').enable();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what *exactly* is wrong here but I suspect this piece in your comboA is not getting fired as expected -

```
comboB.store.reload({
                params: {
                    id: this.getValue()
                }
            })
```

So comboB is still disabled. when you click on the comboB trigger, it loads the store and the comboB's store's load listener is kicking in as expected to enable the combo.

Try putting some debug statements or stepping through the piece of code above.